# Easy/Cheap fix to insulating 2x4 exterior wall in Maryland

Tags: insulation

I am living in an rowhouse with exterior walls built of 2x4's.  When it gets really cold in the winter - I can feel the cold coming through the wall of my bedroom when I put my hand on it.  The wall is about 12' wide by 8' tall with 2 windows.  Is there something I can do to better insulate?  The only thing I can think of is to remove the drywall and furr out the wall and re-insulate.  Are there any less destructive and DIY options?

Comment: what is the exterior of the rowhouse made out of: brick, siding, etc?

Comment: The exterior is stucco - I don't want to touch the outside because we are in an HOA community and they will not let me change what the outside looks like.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's currently inside the walls?

Comment: I am assuming batt insulation - I haven't opened the wall up.  The house was built in 1991 - I think building codes require a higher R value now compared to then.  I think all houses in my area are built with 2x6 exterior walls now.

Answer (score 2):

You can have blown-in insulation added after the fact. They will drill small, maybe 1-1/2" holes in the stucco, one above and one below the fire blocks in each section between the studs and blow in the chopped fiberglass material. then they patch the stucco and if you have some of the original leftover paint, they will repaint it. If not they try to match it, but the success of that varies.

Most HOAs will allow this by the way, so long as the contractor is licensed and in some cases pre-approved by the HOA.

This is what it looks like when they are done, pre-painting.
[image]

Comment: On stucco this an effective method. My moms house is steel expanded mesh inside and out. Having blown insulation was the only way to do it.+

Comment: I will have to think about this - wouldn't the batt insulation inside interfere with filling up the cavities?

Comment: If you have batt insulation, then you don't need the blown in kind. I was assuming from your description that there was no insulation. If you have batts now, then stripping the interior walls will not do you any good anyway, because you can't put MORE batts in. Your wall space is dictated by the 2x4s, so the maximum R value you can put inside there is fixed. Adding more just compresses it and it actually is worse. Your only options now involve adding foam board insulation panels inside.